# what is the difference between 'includes' and 'extends' in a use case diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case

If a vending machine has two methods of payment, e.g. cash and points would this be include cash and points from the payment method use case or extends? And if you choose points to pay you have to insert loyalty card to see if you have enough points this is called the validation of loyalty use case, would this extend or include from the points use case?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to show "cash" and "point" payments as use cases, I would create a "payment" use case and generalization between this latter and the two others. 
Concerning the relation between "insert loyalty card" and "point payment" use cases, you have to respond at the following question: 
Will "insert loyalty" use case be **always** included "point payment" use case? If yes, you have a include relationship. If you are able to pay by point with or without inserting your loyalty card you have a extend relationship.